# Cannot run program "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, permissions

I am currently experiencing substantial complications when running the code below:

```
package practice;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ProgramExecutor {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        try{
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the following error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at basicSkills.ProgramExecutor.main(ProgramExecutor.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:185)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 4 more
```

How would I go about resolving it. It appears to be due to a permission issue on my Mac. I have changed the permissions in the Terminal using chmod command with little success. What else could it be? Is it possible to run Eclipse as a super user in order to access this file?

Comment: Its not eclipse, its related to your `java application` permission, `did you try giving execute permission for all user for Terminal app`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The path '/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app' is the path to the Terminal application, which is a directory. The actual executable Terminal program path is:

```
/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
```

this is the path you need in the `exec` call.

Alternatively use the

```
open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
```

command.

Comment: second alternative did the trick (first one still getting access denied), thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/filetransfer.pl": error=13, Permission denied

I resolved the issue giving the permission to the filetransfer.pl script file to execute. I use the terminal to execute the permission command.
My problem is resolved.

chmod 777 filetransfer.pl